# Merge duplicate rows with same values across two columns in a dataframe and add the values in third column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have a dataframe with 3 columns like below:

```
Item1 Item2 Value
Apple Orange 3
Apple Banana 2
Mango Apple 2
Banana Apple 6
Apple Mango 5
Orange Banana 4
Orange Apple 5
```

I want to remove the duplicate rows based on the combinations of two columns Item1 & Item2 and show only one in any order and want to add their values as a result, so as the final output can be:

```
Item1 Item2 Value
Apple Orange 8
Apple Banana 8
Mango Apple 7
Orange Banana 4
```

What would be the best possible way to solve this? Any leads or ideas will be really helpful!

Comment: In any of those solutions replace the column lists  `['Crop1', 'Crop2', 'Crop3']` with your list `['Item1', 'Item2']` and `'Total_pop'` with `'Value'`

Comment: Thanks, @ALollz. Really appreciate the help. It solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

`sort` first

```
df[['Item1','Item2']]=np.sort(df[['Item1','Item2']].values,1)
df.groupby(['Item1','Item2']).Value.sum()
Out[374]: 
Item1   Item2 
Apple   Banana    8
        Mango     7
        Orange    8
Banana  Orange    4
Name: Value, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if exactly what you want since it returns a set as a column instead of `Item1` and `Item2`, but you can use `frozenset` to create a set of values to group by.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'Item1': ['A','B','C'], 'Item2': ['B','A','D'], 'Value': [2,4,9]})
df.groupby((df[['Item1', 'Item2']].agg(frozenset, 1))).sum()
```